# Function of Past Perfect in this excerpt

Tags: tense, past-tense, past-perfect, sequence-of-tenses

The following text is an excerpt from [Roald Dahl's "The Minpins"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Minpins). I highlighted bold all occurrences of Past Perfect in it.

I find it confusing to find "the next moment" directly in front of a Past Perfect instance.
Also, the alternate usage of Past Perfect and Past in consecutive sentences denoting consecutive actions.

Is there a point I am missing?
Or is this whole *Use Past Perfect for actions ended **before** the action in Past* story not to be taken very seriously?
And in the end, it's more a question of style and taste?

> Just then a funny thing happened. Little Billy began to hear somebody whispering in his ear. ... It was the Devil.
>
> "It would be easy," the Devil was whispering, "to climb out through that window. No one would see you. ... "
>
> "What *is* in there?" Little Billy whispered.
>
> "Wild strawberries," the Devil whispered back. ...
>
> These were the words the Devil whispered softly into Little Billy's ear on that sunny summer afternoon.
>
> The next moment, Little Billy **had opened** the window and was climbing out. In a jiffy he **had dropped** silently onto the flowerbed below. In another jiffy he was out through the garden gate. And in yet another jiffy he was standing on the very edge of the great big dark Forest of Sin!
>
> He **had made** it! He **had got** there! And now the forest was all his to explore!

Comment: Basically, yes - *in the end, it's more a question of style and taste*. I don't know where you got the idea that Past Perfect implies "not to be taken very seriously", but that's at least a possibility. Quite likely Dahl wants to focus attention on Little Billy's circumstances ***after*** sneaking out into the forest, so it might make sense to say those "antecedent" activities aren't really all that important. There's no doubt Past Perfect (as opposed to Simple Past) here is *slightly* "marked", so we should assume *some* intended significance (such as *this is just parenthetical background*).

Comment: (That's to say using Past Perfect to set out what happened ***before*** the current "Narrative Reference Time" can have the effect of emphasizing how "special, unusual, unique" that reference time is; it's ***an important moment*** in Little Billy's life.) But this is all about Lit Crit and Opinions, not really suitable issues for this site to be exploring.

Comment: It emphasises the speed with which events happened. After the conversation, the story jumps forward to 'the next moment' when Billy has _already_ opened the window and started to climb out. In each succeeding 'jiffy' (moment), he is one stage further.